# Can't run JS on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had installed Node.js to run JS codes that I was doing on LeetCode, but I wasn't able to run the code with it, after that I installed on VS Code the extension named Code Runner, but this is what I've got on the output:

```
[Running] node "d:\Microsoft VS Code\projects\testing.js"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.075 seconds
```

And here's the code:

```
function sum(a, b) {return a + b;}

sum(10, 20);
```

I really don't know why this is happening... :(

Comment: It worked, but your code doesn't print anything.

Comment: it did, I called the function sum on the last line, and also if I write console.log("Hello World") it returns the same thing...

Comment: How about you open a terminal in your code directory and run `node testing.js` does that work better ? 

You should see an output to the console if you do `console.log("Hello World") at the end. If you do well, code runner extension is broken maybe.

Comment: You called the function—the function doesn’t do anything other than return a value, which you ignore.

Comment: changed the code to only console.log("Hello World") and ran it on a Windows Terminal using node and it returned nothing, just ran the code and give nothing as output...

Comment: Try disabling all extensions to see if the issue resolves. If it doesn't then you can then turn them back on, but if it does then you can turn it on one-by-one to see which one contains this defect.

Comment: I tried reinstalling VS, so this is the only extension that I have got installed right now...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a bit unrelated but since you mention that you do code challenges I find that quick prototyping, or using scratchpads works great to do lots of changes and see them in real time.

Try [REPL](https://repl.it/) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Note: I personally use condesandbox for it, you just put the variable that you want in a console.log() and it will print on it's own as you go

Comment: I haven't heard about REPL, going to give it a try, but I just wanted to use VS Code for the challenges because I really enjoy the IDE, and doing everything (notetaking for logic for example) in just one place would be great for me

Comment: Oh. there is a great extension that can help you in vsCode for that https://quokkajs.com/

Comment: Yes, but that extension doesn't actually run the code right?

Comment: mainly shows the return outputs, the console logs and the values that variable holds. As it implies it's for rapid prototyping. For coding challenges I have found that it's more than enough